# Django formset is not valid- why not?

Tags: django, formset

I am trying to use a form to allow users to upload images to projects stored in a database in my Django project, however, I'm currently getting console output that's telling me that the `formset` I'm using is not valid...

The view that I'm trying to use to upload the images to a project has been defined with:

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    print("Value of project in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", project)

    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    print("Value of presentations in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))
    print("Value of drawing_formset in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", drawing_formset)

    if drawing_formset.is_valid():
        print 'Saving drawing_formset'
        print "Before", [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
        for drawing_form in drawing_formset:
            if drawing_form.instance.budget:
                print 'Instance', drawing_form.instance.budget
                drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
                drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
                drawing.save()
            print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
    else: print 'Drawing formset not valid.',drawing_formset.errors

    budget_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project, prefix="presentations")

    if budget_formset.is_valid() and budget_formset.has_changed():
        updated_budget_presentations = budget_formset.save()
    elif budget_formset.has_changed(): print 'Budget formset not valid.',budget_formset.errors



    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:concept', args=[project_id]))
```

and the console output I'm getting when this view is called is:

> ("Value of project in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", < Project: Test 1 >)
>
> ("Value of presentations in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", [< Budget: Test 1: Version -1 >, < Budget: Test 1: Version -1 >, < Budget: Test 1: Version 0 >, < Budget: Test 1: Version 0 >, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , '...(remaining elements truncated)...'])
>
> ("Value of drawing_formset in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", < django.forms.formsets.DrawingFormFormSet object at 0x10cee3790 >)
>
> Drawing formset not valid. []

So it's clear that the `else` statement in my view is what is being run here, but I'm not sure why, given that the console clearly indicates that the variables all hold the correct data...

What is wrong with the way I am initialising the `drawing_formset` variable here? Is the `queryset` I'm passing into `DrawingUploadFormset(...)` correct? What does `is_valid()` actually check?

**Edit**

I made the change in the accepted answer, so that my declaration of `drawing_formset` is now:

```
        drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))
```

But it seems I'm now getting an 'Internal Server Error' and `MultiValueDictKeyError` on the line:

```
for drawing_form in drawing_formset: #This line is what's causing the MultiValueDictKeyError
```

I don't understand why this is? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formset does not contain any data. You need to pass `request.POST` and `request.FILES` as the first and second argument (or as the `data` and `files` keyword arguments), but only if it is an actual form submission.

If there is no data passed into a form or formset, it is considered unbound, and will return `False` without checking for errors.

The usual pattern is to pass them when `request.method == 'POST'`, and then validate the formset:

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='drawings', queryset=...)
        if drawing_formset.is_valid():
            # save formset
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
    else:
        drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix='drawings', queryset=...)
    return render(...)  # Render formset
```

This will show a blank form on GET, a filled-in form with error messages on an unsuccessful submission, and it will save the formset and redirect on a successful submission.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think that makes sense, thanks. So would I do this in the `view`, as you have done in your answer? There is a 'Submit' button on the form, which should be handling the actual form submission- but this isn't handled by this `view`...

Comment: If the submission comes from a different view, you can leave out the `else:` branch. However, you'll need to decide what to do when the formset is not valid. Either you need to redirect back (in which case you lose the submitted data), or you need to render the form in this view.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I gave that a go, and I think it's moving me in the right direction, but I now get another error when I click the 'Submit' button to submit the form, having uploaded a PDF to it... The error is an `AttributeError` and says: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files'`... Any idea why this is?

Comment: It should be `request.FILES`, not `request.Files`. Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ah, apologies- missed the typo- but having sorted that, I'm getting a `MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'drawings-4-id'"` when I click the 'Submit' button... I'm not sure why this is?

Comment: The 'Traceback' seems to indicate that the line: `if drawing_formset.is_valid():` is what's responsible for this.

Comment: @someone2088 I'm not sure. You're probably better off asking a new question with more details about your problem.

Comment: So I tried asking a new question, but it's been closed/ marked as a duplicate of this one... I seem to have tracked down my error further- and it appears to be coming from the line `for drawing_form in drawing_formset:` - the errors it is giving are: `Internal Server Error` & `MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'drawings-4-id'" any idea what I'm doing wrong there? Is there something wrong with how I have declared `drawing_formset`? I've updated my OP to show that I'm now doing what you'd suggested in your answer...